# What is the Correct Terraform Provider Configuration for Google Cloud Platform Resources with Beta Arguments?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp, infrastructure-as-code

Terraforming any Google Cloud Platform (GCP) resource defined by any beta arguments requires the `google-beta` provider.  Should the `google-beta` provider be used instead of **or** in tandem with the `google` provider?

In other words, say a certain Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) cluster `$GKE_CLUSTER_NAME` exists within a GCP project `$GCP_PROJECT_NAME`:

```sh
gcloud container clusters list \
--format="value(name)" \
--project=$GCP_PROJECT_NAME

#=>

. . .
$GKE_CLUSTER_NAME
. . .
```

with Config Connector enabled:

```sh
gcloud container clusters describe $GKE_CLUSTER_NAME \
--format=“value(addonsConfig.configConnectorConfig.enabled)” \
--zone=$GKE_CLUSTER_ZONE

#=>

True
```

Terraforming `$GKE_CLUSTER_NAME` requires a `google_container_cluster` resource definition within `container_cluster.tf` that includes both the `config_connector_config` argument (within the `addons_config` block; more [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster#config_connector_config)) and the `provider` argument (missing from the official reference documentation):

```hcl
resource "google_container_cluster" "test" {
  addons_config {
    config_connector_config {
      enabled = true
    }
    . . .
  }
  . . .
  provider        = google-beta
  . . .
}
```

but does **not** require a `google-beta` `provider` definition in `providers.tf`:

```hcl
provider "google" {
  project = ". . ."
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      version = "~> 3.83.0"
    }
  }
}
```

This and the lack of a `provider` argument from other resource definitions, such as a `google_container_node_pool` found in `container_node_pool.tf`, results in the following output from the `providers` command:

```sh
terraform providers

Providers required by configuration:
.
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google] ~> 3.83.0
└── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google-beta]

Providers required by state:

    provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google]

    provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google-beta]
```

after an `apply` command has refreshed the `terraform.tfstate` state file.

Is the more correct and less error-prone method of Terraforming GCP resources with beta arguments?  Or, should I run a `replace-provider` subcommand instead:

```sh
terraform state replace-provider \
-auto-approve \
"hashicorp/google" \
"hashicorp/google-beta"

#=>

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  ~ Updating provider:
    - registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google
    + registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google-beta

Changing 2 resources:

  google_container_node_pool.$GKE_NODE_POOL_NAME

Successfully replaced provider for 1 resources.
```

and modify `providers.tf`:

```hcl
provider "google-beta" {
  project = ". . ."
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    google-beta = {
      version = "~> 3.83.0"
    }
  }
}
```

so that the output of the `providers` command is:

```sh
terraform providers

#=>

Providers required by configuration:
.
└── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google-beta] ~> 3.83.0

Providers required by state:

    provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google-beta]
```

after an `apply` command refreshes the state in `terraform.state`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *should* use **both** `google` and `google-beta` providers.

It is **safe** to use both the `google` and the `google-beta` providers within the same `providers.tf`.  Terraform sends requests for any resource requiring the `google-beta` provider to the Beta endpoint: `https://. . .googleapis.com/v1beta1/. . .`; I.e., using the `google-beta` provider is similar to using the `beta` `gcloud` group.

You *should*:

- include both the `google` and `google-beta` provider in `providers.tf`:

  ```hcl
  provider "google" {
    project = ". . ."
  }

  provider "google-beta" {
    project = ". . ."
  }

  terraform {
    required_providers {
      google = {
        version = "~> 3.83.0"
      }
      google-beta = {
        version = "~> 3.83.0"
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- use the `provider` argument for **every** GCP resource: `google-beta` for any resource that has
  at least one enabled Beta feature:

  ```hcl
  resource "google_container_cluster" "beta_cluster" {
     . . .
     provider        = google-beta
     . . .
  }
  ```

  and `google` for every other resource:

  ```hcl
  resource "google_container_node_pool" "general_availability_node_pool" {
  . . .
    provider       = google
  . . .
  }
  ```

After making **both** of the suggested changes above and *then* running a `refresh`, the output of
the `providers` command should now resemble this:

```sh
terraform providers

#=>

Providers required by configuration:
.
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google] ~> 3.83.0
└── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google-beta] ~> 3.83.0

Providers required by state:

    provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google]

    provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google-beta]
```

You *should* read through the official doc. for provider versions [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_versions).