# Terraforming a Google Kubernetes Engine Cluster with Config Connector Enabled

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp, gcp-config-connector

The Google Kubernetes Engine cluster `$GKE_CLUSTER_NAME` is running inside of Google Cloud Platform (GCP) project `$GCP_PROJECT_NAME` with a matching Terraform configuration stored inside of `container_cluster.tf` that can be checked with:

```sh
terraform plan

#=>

No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.

Terraform has compared your real infrastructure against your configuration and found no differences, so no changes are needed.
```

I wish to enable Config Connector (more on that [here](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/overview)) for `$GKE_CLUSTER_NAME` using Terraform by adding the following arguments to `container_cluster.tf`:

```hcl
resource "google_container_cluster" ". . ." {
  addons_config {
    config_connector_config {
      enabled = true
    }

  . . .

}
```

but when I go to `plan` this change I encounter the following error:

```sh
terraform plan

#=>

╷
│ Error: Unsupported block type
│
│   on container_cluster.tf line 3, in resource "google_container_cluster" ". . .":
│    3:     config_connector_config {
│
│ Blocks of type "config_connector_config" are not expected here.
```

even though the official documentation, found [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster#config_connector_config), states that `config_connector_config` is supported by the `addons_config` block.

I am using the latest versions of Terraform and the `google` provider:

```sh
terraform version

#=>

Terraform v1.0.6
on . . .
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google v3.84.0
```

What change do I need to make so that I can successfully enable Config Connector for `$GKE_CLUSTER_NAME` using Terraform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `config_connector_config` argument is still in **Beta**, so you will need to use the `google-beta` provider for `$GKE_CLUSTER_NAME`:

1. Add the `provider` argument for **every** resource:

   - specify `google-beta` for any resource (e.g., `$GKE_CLUSTER_NAME`) with at least
     *one* Beta argument:

     ```hcl
     resource "google_container_cluster" ". . ." {

        . . .

        provider        = google-beta

        . . .

     }
     ```
   - specify `google` for all other resources:

     ```hcl
     resource resource "google_container_node_pool" ". . ." {

        . . .

        provider       = google

        . . .

     }
     ```

   even though the `provider` arg. is **not** found in the official reference
   documentation for `google_container_cluster` [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster).
2. Add the `google-beta` provider alongside the `google` provider found in a
   `providers.tf` file:

   ```hcl
   . . .

   provider "google" {
     project = ". . ."
   }

   provider "google-beta" {
     project = ". . ."
   }

   . . .

   terraform {
     required_providers {

       . . .

       google = {
         version = "~> 3.84.0"
       }
       google-beta = {
         version = "~> 3.84.0"
       }

       . . .

     }
   }
   ```

   It is **safe** to use both `google` and `google-beta` providers in the same Terraform
   config.  More on that [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_versions#using-both-provider-versions-together).

   **Note**: setting your GCP project name in the provider definitions above allows you
   to run `import` commands (found [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster#import)) without specifying your project.
3. Attempts to `plan` or `apply` your changes so far *can* result in the following:

   ```sh
   terraform plan

   #=>

   ╷
   │ Error: Could not load plugin
   │
   │
   │ Plugin reinitialization required. Please run "terraform init".
   │
   │ Plugins are external binaries that Terraform uses to . . .
   ```

   so you *may* have to `init` again:

   ```sh
   terraform init

   #=>

   Initializing the backend...

   Initializing provider plugins...
   - Finding latest version of hashicorp/google-beta...
   - Reusing previous version of hashicorp/google from the dependency lock file
   - Installing hashicorp/google-beta v3.84.0...
   - Installed hashicorp/google-beta v3.84.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
   - Using previously-installed hashicorp/google v3.84.0

   Terraform has made some changes to the provider dependency selections recorded
   in the .terraform.lock.hcl file. Review those changes and commit them to your
   version control system if they represent changes you intended to make.

   Terraform has been successfully initialized!

   You may now begin working with Terraform. . . .
   ```

   The `providers` command *should* now confirm that `google-beta` is required by your
   current configuration:

   ```
   terraform providers

   #=>

   Providers required by configuration:
   .
   ├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google] ~> 3.84.0
   └── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google-beta] ~> 3.84.0

   Providers required by state:

       provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google]
   ```
4. Run a `plan` to confirm Config Connector will be enabled:

   ```sh
   terraform plan

   #=>

   . . .

   Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
     ~ update in-place

   Terraform will perform the following actions:

     # google_container_cluster.$GKE_CLUSTER_NAME will be updated in-place
     ~ resource "google_container_cluster" ". . ." {

   . . .

         ~ addons_config {

             + config_connector_config {
                 + enabled = true
               }
   . . .

   Plan: 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.

   . . .
   ```

   and then `apply` your changes:

   ```sh
   terraform apply

   #=>

   google_container_cluster.. . .: Modifying... [id=projects/$GCP_PROJECT_NAME/locations/$GKE_CLUSTER_ZONE/clusters/$GKE_CLUSTER_NAME]

   . . .

   google_container_cluster.. . .: Modifications complete after xmxxs [id=projects/$GCP_PROJECT_NAME/locations/$GKE_CLUSTER_ZONE/clusters/$GKE_CLUSTER_NAME]

   Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 1 changed, 0 destroyed.
   ```

   Check to see if Config Connector is enabled for your cluster:

   ```sh
    gcloud container clusters describe $GKE_CLUSTER_NAME \
   --format="value(addonsConfig.configConnectorConfig.enabled)" \
   --zone=$GKE_CLUSTER_ZONE

   #=>

   True
   ```

Want to learn more about using the `google-beta` provider?  Visit [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_versions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69138645).